# Setup default Matrix blocks and default values for sub-fields?

Tags: matrix, control-panel

Question is
what table can't achieve, can be achieve by matrix but problem is matrix cannot have default row value like table have.

Anyway to achieve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need default Matrix blocks or default values for your Matrix block types?

Comment: @carlcs What if both? How to achieve it? =)

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to have default values for most field types and it is also not possible to have default matrix block already added to your new entries.

If there was [an event](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events) that gets raised before an entry is displayed in the Control Panel's "Edit Entry" view, you could set default values rather easily with a custom business logic plugin.

There's no such event available yet, but you could vote for the feature request I just added:

[Raise an event before entry is edited/loaded in CP](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7494886-raise-an-event-before-entry-is-edited-loaded-in-cp)