# Hide (or disable) an entry field in CP depending on user group permission?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, entries-field, permissions

So I am trying to hide (or disable) a field in the "Edit Entry" view in the CP.

I know how to test a user group :
`{% if currentUser.isInGroup('groupHandle') %}`

But I cannot find a hook in Craft Doc to change the rendering of my field ?
Perhaps with `getInputHtml()`? But I dont understand exactly how...

Comment: This is quite close to a solution : http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/get-the-current-entry-element-in-the-cp-edit-entry-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so here is my solution :
1/ define a custom permission for user groups

```
public function registerUserPermissions()
{
    return array(
        'updateTopNews' => array('label' => Craft::t('Update Top News')),
    );
}
```

2/ simply add css to hide the field when user has not the permission in my plugin init function

```
 public function init () {
    parent::init();

    $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
    if ( craft()->request->isCpRequest() && $user ) {

        if ( !$user->can('updateTopNews') ) {
            craft()->templates->includeCss('#fields-topNews-field { display: none; }');
        }
    }
```

Comment: You better don't tell them, they can give themselves the "permission" with the web inspector tools. ;)

Comment: Yeah dont worry my user are not tech savy no prob on that ! :)